# Swing: how do I close a dialog when the ESC key is pressed?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

GUI development with Swing.

I have a custom dialog for choosing a file to be opened in my application; its class extends `javax.swing.JDialog` and contains, among other components, a `JFileChooser`, which can be toggled to be shown or hidden.

The `JFileChooser` component already handles the ESC key by itself: when the file chooser is shown (embedded in my dialog) and I press ESC, the file chooser hides itself.

Now I would like my dialog to do the same: when I press ESC, I want the dialog to close. Mind you, when the embedded file chooser is shown, the ESC key should only hide it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use `InputMap` and `ActionMap` for dealing with key actions in Swing. To close the dialog cleanly, send a window closing event to it.

From my now defunct weblog:

```
private static final KeyStroke escapeStroke = 
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0); 
public static final String dispatchWindowClosingActionMapKey = 
    "com.spodding.tackline.dispatch:WINDOW_CLOSING"; 
public static void installEscapeCloseOperation(final JDialog dialog) { 
    Action dispatchClosing = new AbstractAction() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
            dialog.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent( 
                dialog, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING 
            )); 
        } 
    }; 
    JRootPane root = dialog.getRootPane(); 
    root.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put( 
        escapeStroke, dispatchWindowClosingActionMapKey 
    ); 
    root.getActionMap().put( dispatchWindowClosingActionMapKey, dispatchClosing 
    ); 
}
```

Comment: @Tom hello, thanks for the great post, can you also tell me the best practice in case I've any text base component in the dialog. Since it doesn't work if the focus is on them.

Answer (score 74):

You can use the following snippet.  This is better because the rootPane will get events from any component in the dialog.  You can replace setVisible(false) with dispose() if you want.

```
public static void addEscapeListener(final JDialog dialog) {
    ActionListener escListener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dialog.setVisible(false);
        }
    };

    dialog.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(escListener,
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0),
            JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

}
```

Comment: Sounds nice. I'd just replace dialog.setVisible(false) with some code to actually cancel the dialog. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 17):

If your looking for a technique using new features of Java 8 , try a lambda expression:

```
dialog.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(e -> {
    window.dispose();
}, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```

or

```
KeyStroke k = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0);
int w = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
dialog.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(e -> window.dispose(), k, w);
```

Answer (score 4):

I had problems implementing both of the top answers. Here's a rather compact version using `AbstractAction` to auto-implement most of `Action`'s methods, which works within text-based fields (per @pratikabu's request):

```
final AbstractAction escapeAction = new AbstractAction() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        dispose();
    }
};

getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "ESCAPE_KEY");
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("ESCAPE_KEY", escapeAction);
```

#### References

- the above answers
- http://www.coderanch.com/t/335357/GUI/java/KeyPressed-JDialog

Comment: Small note to others. I found out that if you don't make `escapeAction`, `final`, then you will get an exception. It didn't show up in my IDE that it had to be `final`. Exception showed up during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine, I add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> as closing shorcut aswell

```
    Action closeAction = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
        }
    };

    KeyStroke esc = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE,0);
    getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(esc, "closex");
    getRootPane().getActionMap().put("closex", closeAction);

    KeyStroke ctrlW = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control W");
    getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(ctrlW, "close");
    getRootPane().getActionMap().put("close", closeAction);
```