# Java: How to add a shortkey to a component

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts

In the `JMenuItem` class you can add a shortkey. Is this possible to add this shortkey to a component or the application without using a `JMenu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642925/swing-how-do-i-close-a-dialog-when-the-esc-key-is-pressed) should get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Components that extend `AbstractButton` have methods that allow you to set the mnemonic or accelerator. For other you need to do this yourself.

All Swing components use Key Bindings (even the `JMenu` you describe above). It works by binding a `KeyStroke` to an `Action`. To find all the current Swing bindings you can check out [Key Bindings](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=key-bindings). The entry also include a link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Key Bindings".

Answer (score 0):

Not only buttons may have mnemonics. Mnemonics (shortcuts) for other components may be specified indirectly through their labels.

You need to create a label for the component and [setDisplayedMnemonic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setDisplayedMnemonic%28int%29) for it. Then you attach the label to a component using [setLabelFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setLabelFor%28java.awt.Component%29). The code looks like this:

```
JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("Text 1");
lab1.setDisplayedMnemonic('e');
JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(20);
lab1.setLabelFor(tf1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could attach a [KeyListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) to any component.

You could process they keystrokes there and process the action desired:

See the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for a complete example:

Comment: You could but thats not the way Swing was designed to be used. Swing introduced InputMaps and ActionMaps for this purpose.

Comment: @camickr: At least that's an option :) Thanks for the comment ;)